# json_encode doesn't output to echo correctly - CodeIgniter 3, PHP 7.4 + NGINX, Ubuntu 18

Tags: php, nginx, codeigniter-3, fpm

I have a strange problem. There is an Ajax request (POST), which sends data to the CodeIgniter 3 endpoint and everything is ok. The data is send and I can access it there, but in the PHP, when I try something like:

```
echo json_encode([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Not found'
]);
```

- empty response

The only way to output this is to 'echo' something BEFORE that like this:

```
echo 1;
echo json_encode([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Not found'
]);
```

- `1{"success":false,"message":"Not found"}`

It can be a char or a bool true (which is 1 in the browser response) and it must be before `json_encode`.

I have tried to set up headers to the response `json` or `html`, but with no effect.
It is the same and with `Postman.`

Edit.

This works, too:

```
echo json_encode('test');
```

, but I need a collection.

Comment: Well, this doesn't make much logical sense. Where do you check the response? In your browser's debug panel? Have you tried posting to it with your browser (without ajax)?

Comment: Try use `return json_encode(` and add header json response.

Comment: Could you post your js?

Answer (score 0):

```
     return json_encode([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Not found'
        ]);
```